# Are my normals okay like this?

Tags: texturing, shaders, normals, normal-map

I just did a normal pass on my render and noticed that the colours are vivid red and green, as opposed to the light purple that I was expecting.

I was wondering why this is and if/how I should fix it. I am planning on putting this project in my surfacing portfolio and just want to make sure all my AOVs look professional and industry standard.

[image][image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Seems pretty normal to me  AFAIK the channels of a normal pass only represent the worldspace XYZ orientation. If you rendered the default cube, it would be full red/green/blue on the faces facing +X, +Y and +Z respectively. Your models are mostly made of flat surfaces, seemingly aligned with the world, so you don't get much color. Also Normal passes don't look like normal maps.